# Open Source alternatives to Windows Live Writer

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation

Is there any open source software that can rival Windows Live Writer

Comment: Windows Live is a family of products. What are you looking for? IM?

Comment: @Lekensteyn Most likely IM, Windows Live messenger it is still  very popular in Latin America

Comment: Edited my question. Looking for blogging tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drivel - GNOME client for working with online journals, also known as weblogs or simply "blogs". It retains a simple and elegant design while providing many powerful features, including: Support for LiveJour ...

BloGTK - weblog client that allows you to post to your weblog from GNOME without the need for a separate browser window. BloGTK allows you to connect with many weblog systems such as Blogger, Movable Type, WordPress, ...

ScribeFire - extension for the Browser that integrates with your browser to let you easily post to your blog: you can drag and drop formatted text from pages you are browsing, take notes, and post to your blog. Avail ...

Blogilo - blogging client for KDE, which supports famous blogging APIs.

GNOME blog - desktop blogging application for Linux and Unix. Easy and quick to use to help you writing your great blog posts.Any bugs or feature requests should be done through Bugzilla.Features Simple to use inte ...

You should use all to have an opinion. It is a good idea to check their reviews in Ubuntu Software Center.

[source](http://alternativeto.net/software/windows-live-writer/?platform=linux)

Answer (score 1):

Nope there are no alternatives to windows live since it is a windows (hotmail) service. Have a look at this website: http://alternativeto.net/ for opensource alternatives to proprietary software.

what exactly do you mean with is there an alternative to Windows Live? do you perhaps  mean "is there a client which you can use to chat with your windows live friends using your hotmail account"? If yes, install Pidgin. Have a look at this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7F1J_Szvc7Y

Comment: Sorry was in such a hurry when I was typing. Meant to type Windows Live Writer

Answer (score 1):

Bloglio could be what you are looking for. I believe this is one of the better options out there.
http://blogilo.gnufolks.org/
Pretty sure it is in the SoftwareCentre.
Hope this helps.
Or BloGTK if you prefer, Bloglio is a KDE application.